# navbar is not appearing on mobile phones view

Tags: html, css

my problem is when i press on the hamburger menu the whole menu does not appear (in mobile view) - even though i'm sure about the code and it working properly, the only problem in mobile view i can't diplay all the main menu ( work - blog - contact ) so when i hover on the icon i don't get anything.

```css
nav-bar {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.main-menu {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.main-menu li {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

.main-menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.main-menu a:hover {
  text-decoration: overline;
}

.main-menu li i {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.logo {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 200px;
}

.logo img {
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.menu-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

.main-menu {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 60rem) {
  /*Desktop view*/
  .nav-bar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    min-height: 70px;
  }
  .main-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: 30px;
  }
  .main-menu li {
    margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
  }
  .main-menu a {
    margin-left: 40px;
  }
  /* Hide the menu toogle icon when the full menu is visible */
  .menu-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-bar">
  <!-- The Toggle Button is used to hide and show the menu for a Mobile Layout -->
  <span class="menu-toggle">
         <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </span>
  <a href="#" class="logo">
    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo">
  </a>
  <ul class="main-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Works</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-university"></i>Blogs</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-headset"></i>Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue was that the menu wasn't being hidden / shown. I corrected that and added a css transition. You can use js instead of the input to keep track of the menu state on mobile.

```css
.nav-bar {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.main-menu {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.main-menu li {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px auto;
}

.main-menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.main-menu a:hover {
    text-decoration: overline;
}

.main-menu li i {
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.logo {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 200px;
}

.logo img {
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.menu-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: black;
    font-size: 24px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}

#menu-toggle-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.active {
    display: block;
}

.main-menu {
    transform: translate(100%);
    transition: transform 1s;
}

@media screen and  (min-width: 60rem) {
    /*Desktop view*/
    .nav-bar {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        min-height: 70px;
    }

    .main-menu {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin-right: 30px;
        transform: translate(0%);
    }

    .main-menu li {
        margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
    }

    .main-menu a {
        margin-left: 40px;
    }

    /* Hide the menu toogle icon when the full menu is visible */
    .menu-toggle {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media screen and  (max-width: 60rem) {
  .menu-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  
  #menu-toggle-checkbox:checked + .logo + .main-menu {
    transform: translateX(0)
  }

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<nav class="nav-bar">
        <!-- The Toggle Button is used to hide and show the menu for a Mobile Layout -->
        <label class="menu-toggle" for="menu-toggle-checkbox">
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle-checkbox"/>
        <a href="#" class="logo">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo">
        </a>
        <ul class="main-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Works</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-university"></i>Blogs</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-headset"></i>Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main-menu CSS is set to display none for mobile.

```css
.main-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

You need to tell it what to do like you did with desktop:

```css
.main-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```